# Ensure data is not lost during AWS S3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-datasync

I need to copy all contents of an S3 bucket to another S3 bucket. Planning to use **s3 sync**.

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket
```

After this process, is there any way to verify if all data is migrated to the new bucket? (i.e no data is missed or lost)

Or is there any guarantee that data will not be lost (specified anywhere in official doc?)?

Comment: sync command works in a way that it skips or copy the content based on filesize and timestamp, if you don't want anything to be missed, use cp, it will make sure that exact same objects copied over to the destination bucket, even if objects with the same name ,size and timestamp are present, it'll override.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this verification done after the sync is terminated. S3 provides MD5 hash of objects as `ETag`. You can traverse through your local directory making sure that object does exists in the S3 bucket and integrity can be verified by comparing the local and remote MD5 hashes. 
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#RESTObjectGET-responses)